# 3D projection in 2D using the light-source concept

Tags: geometry, 3d

To achieve 3D projection in 2D I use the light-source concept ( that I got to know in this forum it self ) , so basically I determine a light source with 3D coordinates $(0 ,0 , h)$ and so the 2D coordinates of a point $(x ,y ,z)$ are $$\left(x\ \frac{h}{h + z} ,y\ \frac{h}{h + z}\right) .$$
The question is:

> Can I change the light source coordinates from $(0, 0, h)$ to $(h_1, h_2, h_3)$, and if it is possible, what will be the 2D coordinates resulting.

Comment: Do a translation of the axes to move $(h_1,h_3,h_3)$ to $(0,0,h)$.

Comment: And how can i do so ? In simple words please

Comment: I guess this is easily done with a transformation matrix, but what does this 2D point represent?

Comment: I don't know yet what a transformation matrix is , i just completed my baccalauriat so my math bagage is still quiet small . For the point it's just an arbitrary point , make it a vector if you like .

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay, now I found time to answer.
As I told you in the comments make a translation of the axes before and after the projection: let $P\equiv(x, y, z)$, $L\equiv(h_1,h_2,h_3)$ and $Q$ be the projected point in 3D space.

First we translate to have only the third coordinate of the light source not null: $P'\equiv(x-h_1, y-h_2, z)$ and $L\equiv(0,0,h_3)$.

Now we can use your formula on $P',L'$: $ Q'\equiv ((x-h_1) * {h _3 \over h_3 + z},(y -h_2)* {h _3\over h_3+ z}, 0)$.

Finally we translate $Q'$ in the opposite direction of the first translation:  $ Q\equiv ((x-h_1) * {h _3 \over h_3 + z}+h_1,(y -h_2)* {h _3\over h_3+ z}+h_2, 0)$.

Discard the third coordinate and you have your position in 2D space.